# max_id for twitter api and pagination, very confused

Tags: python, twitter

next,im trying to get more than 100 tweets from a specific hashtag and i'm not quite sure how to do the pagination here either.

```
url = API_ROOT + 'search/tweets.json'
params = {
    'q': '#TrumpCup',
    'result_type': 'recent',
    'count':100,
}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
search_data = resp.json()
```

please don't refer me to any of the twitter help sites, i've looked through everything, i'm just really brain dead when it comes to pagination, I don't quite get how to use the functions built in such as max_id.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like it should be 2 separate questions.

Comment: i actually solved the first part, so now just getting more than 100 tweets at a time

Comment: [here](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/basics/pagination) I see that whenever you encounter a 'next cursor' field in your response you need to add cursor(as a param in your next request) plus whatever value you got in your response. Have you tried that? What are you getting as a response?

Comment: I saw that, but I'm trying to get 1000 tweets, so I feel like that would take a long time to enter every previous cursor, there has to be an easier way.